# How to compare elapsed times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple jQuery game with the score being the elapsed time from begin to finish. Currently I'm adding the elasped time to a simple div:

```
var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
$('.score').html('"<div>" + elapsedTime + "</div>"');
```

Is there a way for me to compare the latest elaspedTime with the previous elaspedTime to keep the quicker time/lower number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read back the previous time and compare it with the new calculated time.

```
var current_time = $('.score').text();
var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
if (elapsedTime < current_time) {

   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will return the lowest of the two times:

```
Math.min(lastElapsedTime, newElapsedTime)
```

For your code you'd probably want...

```
elapsedTime = Math.min(elapsedTime, new Date().getTime() - startTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these scores to an array, and then sort.

```
var scores = [];
scores.push(elapsedTime1);
scores.push(elapsedTime2);
scores.push(elapsedTime3);

//sort it
scores.sort();
// if you want reverse order
scores.reverse();

//get the max and min, but if you have sorted already, that's not necessary.
var min = Math.min.apply(null, scores);
var max = Math.max.apply(null, scores);
```

Comment: This is the best idea so far, can you tell me how I can insert the new elasped time into the array automatically as the users finish the game?

Comment: @user1193783 There is nothing difficult to do that, you could do that in the callback function when user finish the game.